# JSF - link not working properly

Tags: html, jsf, web-applications, web

Hello I have a littele problem with a image which should link to a certain wikipedia page.

**Code:**

```
<a href="#{lc.generateWiki()}">
    <h:outputText value="#{lc.generateWiki()}" />
    <h:graphicImage id="avatar" url="#{lc.generateAvatar()}"
                    width="100px" height="150px" />
</a>
```

the method (`generateWiki()`) gives back the right link, but when I click the page it always redirects to the following link :

`http://localhost:8081/lab3/de.wikipedia.org/wiki/xxxxxxx`

So each time `localhost:8081/lab3` is prefixed to the link.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does generateWiki() return an absolute URL? It should return something like `http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/xxxxxxx`

Comment: ok, this was the problem, it didn't return the http:// Thx for your help it is working now :)